# 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal' to type 'TestApp.SecurityUser'.' in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a custom user class which inherits from ClaimsPrincipal class in my asp.net core application like this

```
public class SecurityUser : ClaimsPrincipal
{
   private bool _isOwnerUser  =false;
   public bool IsOwnerUser
   {
      get { return _isOwnerUser; }
   }
}
```

And then in my controller, I am trying to cast my principal claims to my custom SecurityUser like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  protected SecurityUser SecurityUser
  {
    get
    {
       if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return (SecurityUser)HttpContext.User;
       else return null;
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal' to type 'TestApp.SecurityUser'.'

which means ClaimsPrincipal is not able to cast to my custom security user.

I don't understand why this is not possible, because in my asp.net application, SecurityUser class inherited from IPrincipal and I was able to cast like this

```
protected  SecurityUser SecurityUser
{
  get
  {
    if (this.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) return (SecurityUser)this.HttpContext.User;
    else return null;
  }
}
```

`HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true

Answer (score -1):

Your class SecurityUser implements the right interface, but that doesn't mean the instance in HttpContext.User is indeed an instance of SecurityUser.

You can not cast an instance of object A to object B.. even though they both implement the same interface.

The interface is just a mean to access an particular object, without having to know what kind of object is actually is.

What you probably want here are extension methods, to add the functionality you need.

Comment: But my asp.net application is working correctly with this same implementation