# Unable to cast object of type 'ClaimsIdentity' to type 'MyBespokeIdentity' (NET 8)

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core

We're currently migrating a .Net Framework 4.8 app into .Net 8.  In the old app we have a custom identity class that has properties for easily accessing claims throughout the application, e.g.

```
public class MyBespokeIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
    {
        public const string CustomerIdClaimName = "CustomerId";

        public CustomerIdentity(IEnumerable<Claim> claims, string authenticationType, string nameType, string roleType) : base(claims, authenticationType, nameType, roleType)
        {
        }

        public int CustomerId
        {
            get
            {
                return Convert.ToInt32(FindFirst(CustomerIdClaimName).Value);
            }
            set
            {
                AddClaim(new Claim(CustomerIdClaimName, value.ToString()));
            }
        }
}
```

Within a controller or page we previously did this to get the claim values:

```
var appUser = ((MyBespokeIdentity)User.Identity);
DoSomething(appUser.CustomerId); // gets the claim value
```

However within ASP.Net Core 8 this no longer seems to work.  Now we get this error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity' to type
> 'MyApp.Shared.Classes.User.MyBespokeIdentity'.

I understand about casting type A to type B, and it appears [somebody else has asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791865/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-security-claims-claimsprincipal-to-type) some time ago, but the answer doesn't appear to be complete given the OP is querying *why* this doesn't work in Core when it worked previously?  Can anyone please provide a fuller explanation as to what the issue is, and any recommendation to overcome it?

Comment: Why would it be of type MyBespokeIdentity in the controller? How do you pass it? If it's a JWT token or something, it will be just a ClaimsIdentity type in the HttpContext.

Comment: We use a custom authentication attribute on the controller to perform authentication and return that particular type.  Also in .Net Core Razor/Blazor pages the login routine creates the identity using the bespoke class and ensures the valid claims are created.

Comment: Well, this attribute/routine apparently don't do their job anymore, because User.Identity is not of your type anymore but a normal ClaimsIdentity. Start looking there or post more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET Framework, it was possible to use a custom ClaimsIdentity by setting it during authentication. The custom ClaimsIdentity object is carried along and when you access User.Identity you get the custom identity object that can be casted to your custom identity type.

However, in ASP.NET Core, the User property of the ControllerBase class is an instance of ClaimsPrincipal, which itself carries an Identity property of type ClaimsIdentity. When a user is authenticated, the middleware creates a ClaimsPrincipal with one or more ClaimsIdentity instances attached. By default, these identities are instances of ClaimsIdentity, not any custom subclass thereof.

You could solve this with Extension Methods on the ClaimsPrincipal to simplify Claims Access, e.g.:

```
public static class ClaimsPrincipalExtensions
{
    public const string CustomerIdClaimName = "CustomerId";

    public static int GetCustomerId(this ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));

        var claim = principal.FindFirst(CustomerIdClaimName);
        if (claim == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The customer ID claim is not present on the principal.");

        return Convert.ToInt32(claim.Value);
    }
}
```

Then, in the controller, you can use:

```
var customerId = User.GetCustomerId();
DoSomething(customerId);
```

Comment: That's a nice explanation and example, thank you.   For a bonus, do you know why this behaviour was changed in Core? Also how does a developer become acquainted with the depths of Core at this level when there's so little documentation?!?

Comment: Warning: I just migrated from .NET 7 to .NET 8 and `FindFirst()` is returning a different item than before (there are two!). I am looking for `identity/claims/nameidentifier` and it is returning an email instead of a GUID (which I want). Not sure why there are two now - or if they always were but were in a different order before.

Answer (score 1):

In .net core you have to check the claims contained in User property from controllers and extract the claim value you need for the specific action:

Note: I suggest you to use the modern object pattern in c#, it would help you with both casting and null checking in only one syntax:

```
private bool TryGetCustomerId(out int customerId)
{
    customerId = -1;
    if (User.Identity is not ClaimsIdentity identity)
        return false;

    var customerIdClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(
        c => string.Equals(c.Type, "CustomerId"));

    return customerIdClaim is Claim claim && int.TryParse(claim.Value, out customerId);            
}
```